# Issue with Java - odd even letters

Tags: java

I am working on getting the output from user input to just show odd numbers or even numbers if the first `CharAt(0) == 'w'`, as an example.

Does it work by "System.out.println(CharAt(0) + CharAt(2) + CharAt(4))"?

I am working on using the Scanner project to get user input and already have the following input part:

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.print("Please enter a uncoded string: ");
String first = input.nextLine();
input.close();

if (first.charAt(0) == 'u') {
  first = first.toUpperCase();
} else if (first.charAt(0) == 'l') {
  first = first.toLowerCase();
} else if (first.charAt(0) == 'o') {
      first = first.charAt(0) + charAt(2) + charAt (4);
}

System.out.println("The decoded string is: " + first);
```

Is there a way of just having a formula like (0 + odd)?

Comment: I have thought about String int i = o, and then just add 2, 4 etc to select the odd numbers from the input. Just need to try and get it to work depending on the length of word input by user.

Comment: Also, this will then work for even letters, being charAt(1), charAt (3) etc.

Comment: What if input length is 10

Comment: Consider using a loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you're trying to "decode" an "encoded" string by examining its prefix char:

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.print("Please enter a uncoded string: ");
String first = input.nextLine();
input.close();

if (first.charAt(0) == 'u') {
    first = first.toUpperCase();
} else if (first.charAt(0) == 'l') {
    first = first.toLowerCase();
} else if (first.charAt(0) == 'o') {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < first.length(); i = i + 2) {
        sb.append(first.charAt(i));
    }
    first = sb.toString();
} else if (first.charAt(0) == 'e') {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 1; i < first.length(); i = i + 2) {
        sb.append(first.charAt(i));
    }
    first = sb.toString();
}
System.out.println("The decoded string is: " + first);
```

I'm not sure if in the case of the prefix "o" you want this prefix to be included in the result. 
**Edit**  
If you don't like StringBuilder:

```
} else if (first.charAt(0) == 'o') {
    String str = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < first.length(); i = i + 2) {
        str += first.charAt(i);
    }
    first = str;
} else if (first.charAt(0) == 'e') {
    String str = "";
    for (int i = 1; i < first.length(); i = i + 2) {
        str += first.charAt(i);
    }
    first = str;
}
```

Comment: Hi, that works, does it work for even by selecting the chatAt value as "1"         first. int i = 1; i < first.length(); i = i + 2) {       .Again, thanks a million for your help on this.

Comment: It can work for any char you choose. I thought you wanted 'e' for evens.

Comment: You have to change 'e' in the if statement with your chosen char.

Comment: That works, would StringBuilder be a complex String way to do this. I am just starting out and not sure if there is any other way of building a SubString to select the odd and even values.  Thanks again for your help.

Comment: A StringBuider is always preferred over string when it involves multiple concatenations. You can do the same with a string like: `str+= first.charAt(i);`

Comment: Would I just need to replace the str+=first.charAt(i)?

Comment: Thanks yet again!

Comment: Thanks yet again!

Comment: That is brilliant, am just starting off with Java but that makes logical sense. Can follow that, Appreciate your hellp and have noted StringBuilder in my notebook for useful tips too.